# Take URL From File and Display in Iframe

Tags: html, url

I have this html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML Program</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <iframe id='MyFrame' style="width: 80vw; height: 80vh"> </iframe>

    <script>
        const myFile = "settings.txt";
        document.getElementById('MyFrame').setAttribute("src", myFile);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And settings.txt:

```
desmos.com/calculator
```

I'm looking to take an arbitrary URL from the settings.txt file and display that webpage in the iframe, but the iframe is (rightfully) interpreting the url as raw text. How do I tell it to instead display the webpage?

Any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

you have to use XMLHttpRequest to take URL from file and display purpose , modify your script tag to :

```
<script>
    const myFile = "settings.txt";
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', myFile, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            const url = xhr.responseText.trim();
            document.getElementById('MyFrame').setAttribute("src", url);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
</script>
```